# How to do a atomic find and save using mongoose in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In my db, I have a "Thing", whose id is "53e5fec1bcb589c92f6f38dd".
I wanna update the count member in it everytime when doAdd is called.
Like the code below.
But since the find and save operation is separated, I cannot get the desired result..
Any best practice about this situation?
Thanks in advance!

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var ThingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  count: Number,
});

var Thing = mongoose.model('Thing', ThingSchema);

var doAdd = function(id){
  Thing.findById(id,  function(err, thing){ 
    if(******){ 
      #perform some logic...
      thing.count++;
    }
    thing.save();
  });
};

var id = "53e5fec1bcb589c92f6f38dd";
doAdd(id);
doAdd(id);
```

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: @Charminbear thing.count should be increased by 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are expecting to increase the count by 2 as you are calling `doAdd` twice. But here the code in `doAdd` is of asynchronous nature i.e the second `doAdd` call is called before the the first query and save process is completed. The results are unpredictable due to the asynchronous nature of the function. All mongoose queries and the `save` calls are asynchronous.
So if you call

```
thing.save();
console.log('saved!!');
```

The console ouput appears before the document is actually saved because node doesn't wait for the save to be finished. So if you need any operation to be done after the document is saved, you would place it in the callback.

```
thing.save(function(err){
       if(!err){
         console.log('saved');
       }
 });
```

If you want to avoid callbacks have a look at `async` module.